# Error 403 Forbidden when hit the API using retrofit in android

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to hit the API in android using retrofit to get the token from File Browser. It works if I run the command from command prompt like this :

**curl -X POST -d "{"username": "abc", "password": "xyz", "recaptcha": ""}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://xyz:8888/api/login**

But when I hit the api using retrofit it gives an error **403 Forbidden**

```
val user = (""""{\"username\": \"$userName\", \"password\": \"$password\", \"recaptcha\": \"\"}"""")
val tokeResponse = api.getImageToken(Config.imgTokenUrl, user)

 @POST
    suspend fun getImageToken(
        @Url url: String,
        @Body user: String,
        @Header("Content-Type")  content_type: String = "application/json"
    ): Response<String>
```

Comment: 403 means the server received the request and decided you weren't allowed to access it.  You'd have to look at the server side to figure out why, we can't tell from the client code.